# Validate Registration Form in Modal And Submit data in database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

In my modal I have registration form with fields of name,email,password.While using ajax alone i can add my data.now i tried with bootstrap validator.js to validate the user datas.After that my datas are not stored in database is there any connection between that validator.js and ajax.Here i enclose image.After i click submit it is showing like that[image]

If anybody know the solution please help me!! Thanks in advance

Here is my code

addlistener function call for form validation

```
addEventListener('load', prettyPrint, false);

 $(document).ready(function () {    
    $('#registration').submit(function (event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var username = $('#username').val();
        var emailid = $('#emailid').val();
        var datas="username="+username+"&emailid="+emailid;
        $.ajax
            ({
              type:"POST",
             url: "register.php",
             data: datas
             }).done(function(data) {
            $('#register_alert').append(
                '<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">' +
                    '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">' +
                    '&times;</button>' + data + '</div>');
            });
    });
});
```

And My Html Code WIth Modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Create Account</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body row">
            <div id="register_alert"></div>
                <div class="col-md-6 ">
                    <form id="registration">
                        <label>Username</label>
                        <div class="left-inner-addon ">
                        <i class="icon-user"></i><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username" id="username" data-validation="length alphanumeric" data-validation-length="min4" />
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <label>Email ID</label>
                        <div class="left-inner-addon ">
                        <i class="icon-envelope"></i>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email ID" name="emailid" id="emailid" ></div>
                        <br/>
                        <div id="reg">
                        <button class="btn btn-theme btn-block" href="#" id="register" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i>REGISTER</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

And My Validator Code

```
$('#registration').validate({
      rules: {
         username: {
          required: true,
         required: true
        },

     username: {
          minlength: 6,
          required: true
        },

        emailid: {
          required: true,
          email: true
        },

      },
      highlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
      },
      success: function(element) {
        element
        .text('OK!').addClass('valid')
        .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
      }
});
```

Comment: Some code example can help users to answer

Comment: You have the `username` field listed twice within your `rules` object and you also have the `required` rule listed twice under the first instance of `username`.  This structure is going to lead to confusion and unexpected behavior as only the *last* instance of each is going to be used.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/1L9x53ud/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code but the approach is wrong, you are using [jQuery validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org) to validate form and Ajax method call separately, what you could use Ajax method call `$.ajax` inside [submithandler](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#submithandler) and the `jQuery validate` plugin will invoke the submit handler if the validation has passed.

```
$('#registration').validate({
    rules: {
        username: {
            minlength: 6,
            required: true
        },
        emailid: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
    },
    highlight: function(element) {
    $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
    },
    success: function(element) {
        element
        .text('OK!').addClass('valid')
        .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "register.php",
            data: $(form).serialize(),
            }).done(function(data) {
            $('#register_alert').append(
            '<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">' +
                '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">' +
                '&times;</button>' + data + '</div>');
            });
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah, Thank You So Much..Its Working Now.

Comment: In my form validation i would like to validate whether date of birth selected is above 1995.Is this Possible With this validation @Shehary

Comment: Yes it's possible with `remote validation` method, here is an example http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/

Comment: Validationdateofbirth: {
          remote: "checkdob.php",
          required: true
        },

Comment: And checkdob.php                                                                                           <?php
if (!empty($_POST['dateofbirth']))
{
    $dateofbirth = date('Y',strtotime($_POST['dateofbirth']));
    $current=date("Y");
    $age=$current-$dateofbirth;
    $allow="15";
    if($age>$allow)
    {
        return "true";
    }
   else
   {
    return "false";
   }

?>

Comment: if input `name` is `Validationdateofbirth` then in PHP `$_POST['dateofbirth']` should be `$_POST['Validationdateofbirth']` and can you put your code in http://jsfiddle.net n save it, paste link here so can have closer look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103083/discussion-between-kavya-shree-and-shehary).

Comment: @Sparky already pointed out in discussion in chat and resolved the issue, forget to update the answer